# Simulating a game of craps 1000 times

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, while-loop

I'm using random in Python to simulate a game of craps. I'm then simulating the game n amount of times to see how often the player beats the dealer. I have a test file with seeds to check my code in, but my numbers are just slightly off. I think the mistake is in the structure, but can't seem to figure out what exactly it is.

**The dice roll**

```
def quietRoll():
    return random.randrange(1,7) + random.randrange(1,7)
```

**Craps simulation**

```
def quietCraps():

    #first roll

    firstRoll = quietRoll()
    if firstRoll in (7,11):
        return 1
    elif firstRoll in (2,3,12):
        return 0

    #every other roll

    newDice = quietRoll()
    while newDice not in (7, firstRoll):
        newDice = quietRoll()
        if newDice == firstRoll:
            return 1
        if newDice == 7:
            return 0
```

**Running craps n amount of times**

```
def testCraps(n):
    count = 0
    playerWin = 0
    while count <= n:
        if quietCraps() == 1:
            playerWin += 1
            count += 1
        else:
            count += 1
return playerWin/n
```

**Expected output**

```
Failed example:

random.seed(5)
testCraps(1000)

Expected:
    0.497
Got:
    0.414
```

Comment: And your question is ... what?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz What is causing the expected output to be different from the actual?

Comment: How did you come up with your expected output?

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes It's provided to me in the test file

Comment: The probability that the player will win in craps is closer to 0.493 than 0.497.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
newDice = quietRoll()
while newDice not in (7, firstRoll):
    newDice = quietRoll()
    if newDice == firstRoll:
        return 1
    if newDice == 7:
        return 0
```

If `newDice` lands on `7` or `firstRoll` the first time, you fall off the end of the function without hitting a `return` statement, and the function returns `None` by default.

Since a `return` statement ends the function (stopping any loops the function may be executing and skipping any of the function's remaining code), you could fix this by having the loop be `while True` and not initialize `newDice` before the loop:

```
while True:
    newDice = quietRoll()
    if newDice == firstRoll:
        return 1
    if newDice == 7:
        return 0
```

Alternatively, you could move the `if` checks out of the loop, so they happen once the die has landed on `7` or `firstRoll`, regardless of whether that happens inside or outside the loop:

```
newDice = quietRoll()
while newDice not in (7, firstRoll):
    newDice = quietRoll()
if newDice == firstRoll:
    return 1
if newDice == 7:
    return 0
```

Comment: What would be an alternate way to write it so that does not happen, I'm a beginner so I apologize for the silly question.

Comment: @23k: Answer expanded.